# How to understand transaction controller response time?

Tags: jmeter

I have a transaction controller that contains two HTTP requests. After executing the test, the 90% response time for two HTTP requests is 4 & 5 seconds respectively. But the 90% response time for the transaction controller is 21 seconds. I don't understand how is JMeter giving 21 seconds response time for the parent transaction controller (I assume it should summarize the child HTTP request response times and display 4+5= 9 seconds)? Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Transaction Controller should sum up the response time of all nested [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) and normally the numbers should be consistent:

[image]

However given the situation when your Samplers have [PreProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) or [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) and you tick `Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample` box - the time taken by the aforementioned test elements will also be included into Transaction Controller's Response Time

[image]

[image]

More information: [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Transaction Controller gives the overall response time of the http samples + Timer + any pre or post processors.