# Need help on response time

Tags: jmeter, response-time

Need help on JMeter response result from the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw4NK.png)

**My scenario**: Am calculating Min/Max/Average response time on Api creating a user account.

1.Login to site

2.Using API request creating a user account - (creating 100 users account using API)

3.Logout.

Observation :

- Total elapsed time is 32 mins (which is there in the image).
- Response time for 100 users is 90852.

I need to understand how the response time units are measured here.

1. does 90852 milliseconds mean approximately 90secs.

   So is it like a single user account is created in 90 secs by the API?.

   So, please tell me how response time is working here when it compared with total response time?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average creation of a user took your API 908 ms (the entry with 100 samples ending with /api/users).

Since the line (where the name of the transaction is not in the screenshot) has the sample count 1 and the response time resembles 100*908ms I would guess that you have a Transaction Controller that holds the Loop Controller.

The same hierarchy that you use to organize your test plan also applies to transaction controllers and samplers. So if you group several samplers - and/or transaction controllers - under a parent transaction controller, that parent transaction controller will have the combined response time of all its children.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Correct me if am wrong , so i can understand that  response time is 908ms (0.9 seconds ) for creating a single user account using api . if that is the case how total elapsed time is 32mins ?

Comment: I cannot answer that question without further knowledge of your test plan and the setup of your thread group(s). It might contain think times/timers or a fixed test duration?

Answer (score 0):

*Response time for 100 users is 90852.* - **No, only for 1 user.** Looking at your image it appears that only 1 sample was collected during 32 mins. So this response time is for that 1 sample not for all 100 users. JMeter only shows you completed responses. Assuming you have a thread group of 100 users, the rest didn't complete / were waiting for the api to respond.

*Does 90852 milliseconds mean approximately 90secs.* - **yes**. In your api you seem to be using once only controller for login and authenticate and everything else seems to be running sequentially. So if you are load testing have a slow api response then you won't be able to measure other throughput for the rest of the apis correctly as the slowest api will hold up the thread for a long time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thread group runs only once .That arrow green arrow near the column in the image is denoting a controller , that is loop controller which loops(100 times) the api to create 100 user account . i mean to say 90852 response time is for a folder .

Comment: 90852 response time is for the individual api unless you are using transaction controller which sums up response time of the group. See this thread for more information on how transaction controller evaluates response time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039592/how-to-understand-transaction-controller-response-time

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide comprehensive analysis without seeing your [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan).

When it comes to your questions:

> Total elapsed time is 32 mins (which is there in the image).

this looks a little bit high for me, given you create 100 user accounts and **average response time is 908** [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) I would expect that your test will finish in 90.8 seconds which is 1.5 minutes.

> does 90852 milliseconds mean approximately 90secs.

it rather looks like a sum of all 100 response times most probably you got it from the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)

Average Response time is basically [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean), to wit sum of all response times divided by their count.

1. First of all you need to understand why does you test take that long.
2. You seem to be creating 100 user accounts using 1 thread (virtual user) in loop, you might want to consider doing it with multiple threads instead
3. You should be using JMeter GUI only for tests development and/or debugging, when it comes to test execution [you should be running your JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```